# How to count item occurences in a list and return a count of zero if it is not in the list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, count

I have a master list, let's name m_list:

```
m_list = ['red','orange','yellow','green','blue','indigo','violet']
```

and I want to count how often the items in m_list occur in another list, lets call it e_list:

```
e_list = ['red','red','red','violet','blue','blue']
```

the desired output would be a dictionary that had the count of every item in `m_list` in `e_list` and have zeros if the item wasn't in `e_list`

something like this:

`{'red':3,'orange':0,'yellow':0,'green':0,'blue':2,'indigo':0,'violet':1}`

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? You don't really need `m_list`, `collections.Counter(e_list)` already gives `0` for any missing key.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have tried ```Counter(e_list)``` and it does not give ```0``` for missing keys

Comment: It doesn't *show* them, because how could it possibly know which of all of the possible keys you consider to be missing? But `collections.Counter(e_list)['yellow'] == 0`, for example.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that is intersting, thank you. I will look into using that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do this is with the `Counter` class from the `collection` module.

```py
>>> from collections import Counter

>>> m_list = ['red','orange','yellow','green','blue','indigo','violet']
>>> e_list = ['red','red','red','violet','blue','blue']

>>> counts = Counter(e_list)          # Count the number of times each entry of e_list appears
>>> for key in m_list:
...     counts.setdefault(key, 0)     # Add other entries of m_list to the counter with a value of 0.
>>> print(counts)
Counter({'red': 3, 'blue': 2, 'violet': 1, 'orange': 0, 'yellow': 0, 'green': 0, 'indigo': 0})
```

The `Counter` class acts just like a `dict`, so you get all of the functionality that you want, as well as some nifty methods like `.most_common()`.

Answer (score 0):

A pretty basic implementation could look like this:

```
m_list = ['red','orange','yellow','green','blue','indigo','violet']
e_list = ['red','red','red','violet','blue','blue']

result = {}
for key in m_list:
    result[key] = e_list.count(key)
```

`result` would exactly look like what you wanted. Just keep in mind that  this is definitely not an efficient solution for longer lists.